# How to scrape linkedin's network's connections

Tags: web-scraping, linkedin-api

I wondered if there is anything available to scrape my linkedin network connections. For example if I have 1 connection on linkedIn I would like to get my connection's connections, so if my connection has 200 connections I would like to get that data if the profile is set to public.

I've tried linkedin helper extension but it's only scraping my connections, without further drilling into my networks connections.

I've tried running scrapedin npm module but it gives me errors on the implementation.

```
const scrapedin = require('scrapedin')

const profileScraper = await scrapedin({ email: 'login@mail.com', password: 'pass' })
const profile = await profileScraper('https://www.linkedin.com/in/some-profile/')
```

Expected result would be an csv with my networks connections which will be a big list if my connections have a lot of other connections. Does anyone used any crawlers or implemented this with the new linkedin website?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this? It implements `scrapedIn` to aggregate connections.

https://github.com/linkedtales/scrapedin-linkedin-crawler